# Scheduling a Task coding problem, using bottom up approach

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I have a list of costs and time required for each tasks. I have two servers to run those jobs, where one is paid and the other one is free. To use the free server you have to run a task on the paid one. The paid server takes as much time mentioned in the time array, while the free server can run any task in 1 unit of time. I have to find the minimum cost to run all the jobs with the given constraints.

My Approach:
Top down-

```
@cache
function dfs(job_idx, time_spent)
{
   if job_idx == n {
       if time_spent >= 0:  return 0
       else: return inf
   }
   return min(cost[job_idx]+dfs(job_idx+1, time_spent+time[job_idx]), dfs(job_idx+1, time_spent-1))
}
dfs(0, 0)
```

This is my top down approach using dfs where I traverse all the possible solutions considering that job as paid/free and I am trying to solve it using bottom up approach, but I am not able to think how I should go about it. I can either solve dp problems using either approaches top down/bottom up but can't think how to convert either to another. Since i am good at dfs, I can solve it using top-down and for bottom up I have learned some patters to take the approach. Helpful link for patterns: https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/458695/dynamic-programming-patterns

This is what I follow to was learning to understand it:

1. Identify the recursive function.
2. Identify the base case for the recursive function
3. Create a 2D array that will hold the results of the subproblems.
4. Fill in the base cases of the array. These are the values that the recursive function returns when it reaches the base case.
5. Use a nested loop to iterate over the nodes or vertices and the states of the subproblem. Fill in the remaining values of the array using the results of the previous subproblems.
6. Return the result that corresponds to the initial state of the subproblem

Can someone please help with any explanation that might help me think both ways?

Comment: Top down and bottom up are different skills.  I wouldn't try to convert one to the other.  And this problem, believe it or not, I'd solve with an A* search.

Comment: Can you give me some idea/algo where I can start thinking about? And why do you think A* is better then dfs/dp how did you figure that out? I have not worked with A* algorithm practically so any starting reference would be appreciated!

Comment: The description says "To use the free server you have to run a task on the paid one" -- could you please help me understand where in your formulation that dependency is expressed? Also, could you please explain why the time parameter is significant or used at all? The description says to minimise cost and there is no mention of how time can affect the cost.

Comment: The overall problem is to find the minimal cost to get those tasks done, with the constraints that if you want to use a free server, you must run another job on the paid to utilize the free server. So you might want to schedule the jobs which take a very long to be run on the free servers since it can be done in a unit of time, while less time consuming jobs on the paid server to reduce cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, all three solutions, outlined.

Top down is usually easiest.  "Write a recursive function, memoize."  Here is an untested recursive function.

```
def cost_at (idx, free_time_left):
    if idx == len(cost):
        if 0 <= free_time_left:
            return 0
        else:
            return float('inf')
    else:
        cost_paid = cost_at(idx+1, free_time_left + time[idx]) + cost[idx]
        cost_unpaid = cost_at(idx+1, free_time_left - 1)
        return min(cost_paid, cost_unpaid)
```

And now memoize.

```
def cost_at (idx, free_time_left):
    if idx == len(cost):
        if 0 <= free_time_left:
            return 0
        else:
            return float('inf')
    else:
        if (idx, free_time_left) not in cache:
            cost_paid = cost_at(idx+1, free_time_left + time[idx]) + cost[idx]
            cost_unpaid = cost_at(idx+1, free_time_left - 1)
            cache[(idx, free_time_left)] = min(cost_paid, cost_unpaid)
        return cache[(idx, free_time_left)]
```

There are lots of libraries that let you simply cache things and not worry too much about the structure of the cache.  But the structure matters.  This cache can be written in various ways but all boil down to:

```
by idx
    by free time left
        cost
```

This is a depth first search with caching.  To mechanically turn this into a bottom up solution we need to switch to a breadth first search.

That is we need to switch to finding what all of the possibilities are for `idx = 0`, then `idx = 1`, and so on.  But with a twist.  The top down solution stores the best cost FROM this point on.  The bottom up solution stores the best cost TO this point.  So something like this (untested)

```
def min_cost ():
    # At the start we have 0 free time left, for a cost of 0.
    prev_state = {0: 0}
    for idx in range(len(cost)):
        this_state = {}
        for (free_time_left, prev_cost) in prev_state.items():
            # Try unused
            if free_time_left-1 not in this_state or prev_cost < this_state[free_time_left-1]:
                this_state[free_time_left-1] = prev_cost
            # Try used
            free_time_left += time[idx]
            prev_cost += cost[idx]
            if free_time_left not in this_state or prev_cost < this_state[free_time_left]:
                this_state[free_time_left] = prev_cost
        prev_state = this_state
return min((
    prev_cost for (free_time_left, prev_cost) in prev_state.items()
        if 0 <= free_time_left
))
```

Note that previously we were caching with a key of `(idx, free_time_left)`. But now we throw away the previous `idx` as soon as we're done processing it.  Saving us time.

That's it for bottom up, right?  Sorry, no.

Bottom up is its own skill.  We are currently storing every relationship `prev_state[free_time_left] = prev_cost` which is the same as storing a bunch of pairs `(free_time_left, prev_cost)`.  But we don't actually need to store EVERY one of these pairs.  We can get rid of any pair where there is another pair with the same or more `free_time_left`, and the same or less `prev_cost`.  Because that other solution will lead to an best answer that cannot be worse than this one, so this one can be dropped immediately.

This leads to the idea of an *optimal fringe*, where we have an array of `[(time1, cost1), (time2, cost2), ...]` stored by increasing time and decreasing cost.  That lets us do the following (again untested).

```
def min_cost():
    fringe = [(0, 0)]
    for idx in range(len(cost)):
        fringe_unused = [(x[0]-1, x[1]) for x in fringe]
        fringe_used = [(x[0]+time[idx], x[1]+cost[idx]) for x in fringe]
        fringe = []
        i = 0
        j = 0
        while i < len(fringe_unused) and j < len(fringe_used):
            # Find which pair to add to the fringe next.
            if i < len(fringe_unused):
                if len(fringe_used) <= j or fringe_unused[i][0] < fringe_used[j][0]:
                    pair = fringe_unused[i]
                    i += 1
                else:
                    pair = fringe_used[j]
                    j += 1
            else:
                pair = fringe_used[j]
                j += 1
            
            # Remove the pairs in the fringe that are worse than this.
            while 0 < len(fringe) and pair[1] <= fringe[-1][1]:
                fringe.pop()
            # And add it.
            fringe.append(pair)
    i = 0
    while fringe[i][0] < 0:
        i += 1
    return fringe[i][1]
```

While the previous bottom up solution saved memory but not time, THIS one saves BOTH memory AND time.  Because it avoids looking at possibilities that can't lead to an optimal solution.

This kind of "figure out and preemptively drop suboptimal states" logic is something that you need experience with bottom up to spot.  But it can make a huge performance difference.

Now, what about my [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) comment?

People think of A* search as a graph algorithm.  But it does far more.  For an example of code I wrote to do that for a related problem, see [Algorithm using a combination of numbers to achieve a target or exceed it in the most efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098348/algorithm-using-a-combination-of-numbers-to-achieve-a-target-or-exceed-it-in-the/75100118#75100118).

So how do I spot that I could use the technique here, and it would be good.  Well, here is my thinking.

1. Try to think up a greedy solution that is close.
2. Based on the greedy solution, come up with a heuristic that is a lower bound.
3. A* search is probably going to do well.

That's more code than I want to write, but I'll outline how you tackle this.

First, let's try to be greedy.  We want to schedule paid jobs that get the most tasks done per dollar.  The cost of a job is `cost[idx]`.  The number of jobs that complete while it is on the paid server is `1 + time[idx]`.  The jobs/dollar is therefore `(1 + time[idx])/cost[idx]`.  If we sort the job indexes by that, and put enough of the starting list on the paid server then the rest on the free server, we'll get a pretty good solution.  The only problem is that the very last job put on the paid server may run longer than we like.

So let's sort the job indexes in that order anyways.  (Break ties in favor of shorter first.)  We're doing to do a search.  For each index, the job goes on the paid server, or the free one.

But to do A* search, we need to estimate the cost of finishing.  That is, we are prioritizing by a lower bound on the total cost.  Which is that spent so far, plus a lower bound on the cost remaining.  But we can get a lower bound on the cost remaining by saying, "What if we just filled it in greedy, but can stop partway through the last task when the partial time on the last paid task and the last free task add up to a whole task?"  That's obviously a lower bound, and it is probably pretty good.

That sounds like a lot of work to compute, can we precompute something to make it easy?  Of course!  We can create an array, by the last task assigned to the paid server of `(cost_so_far, tasks_done)`.  We can then figure out a bound from where we are to some future point by taking greedy to that future point and subtracting greedy to now.  This makes it easy to search for the right future point to finish from where we are.

This is enough to code an A* search for the optimal answer.  That search will start by trying greedy, greedy, greedy until it realizes how much the last one goes over.  It will then start backtracking and doing a real search.  If greedy was the answer, or close, it will be very fast.  If you have to do a lot of backtracking, in the worst case you can degrade down to the equivalent of top down dynamic programming with a bit of up front work.  But usually it is simply fast.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a wonderful detailed explaination! I will try to write an algorithm that uses A* approach as you have outlined. It was really a very detailed solution and I really appreciate you taking time to explain it to me.